# JSP and Stored procedures

Tags: java

I have a JSP page that has two select dropdown menus. Each of the dropdowns is populated from a database using a stored procedure.  One drop down has a name to search and other has an orderno kind of search. selecting either one of that will lead us to next page based on the value of the selected option via pressing a single button.  Right now, I have one select option running successfully. When i tried to introduced the second one, everything got messed up. The page that is getting called has a getparameter call to the select dropdown.

Can any body help me how to incorporate both the select and based on either one of them calls the same page using a button
Here is code..

```
            Search:<INPUT type="text"  name="edSeachInput" >
            Issuer Name:
                    <select name="IMNT" size='10'>
                    <%
                        String sql1 = ("EXEC store_proc_1");
                        ResultSet rs1 = db.runQuery(sql1);
                        while (rs1.next())
                        {
                    %>
                    <option value="<%= rs1.getString("id_imnt") %>"><%= rs1.getString("nm_imnt") %></option>
                    <%
                        }
                        rs1.close();
                    %>
                    </select>


            OR

            Search ISIN:<input type="text" name="ISINSearchInput" >

                    <select name="ISIN" size='10'>
                    <%
                        String sql2 = ("EXEC store_proc_2");
                        ResultSet rs2 = db.runQuery(sql1);
                        while (rs2.next())
                        {
                    %>
                    <option value="<%= rs2.getString("id_imnt_") %>"><%= rs2.getString("order_no") %></option>
                    <%
                        }
                        rs2.close();
                    %>
                    </select>

                <input  type="submit" style= " color:#FFFFFF"  name="drill" class="over" value="Query"  OnMouseOver="rollbg('roll', 'drill')" OnMouseOut="rollbg('over', 'drill')"/>

form>
```

Comment: Hey tom this is what the code looks like

Comment: <form  action="nextpage.jsp" method="POST">
    Search:<INPUT type="text"  name="edSeachInput" >
    Issuer Name:
    <select name="IMNT" size='10'>
    <%
       String sql1 = ("EXEC store_proc_1");
       ResultSet rs1 = db.runQuery(sql1);
       while (rs1.next())
       {
          %>
          <option value="<%= rs1.getString("id_imnt") %>"><%= rs1.getString("nm_imnt") %></option>
          <% }
 rs1.close();
  %>
 </select>
OR

Comment: Search ISIN:<input type="text" name="ISINSearchInput" >
<select name="ISIN" size='10'>
<%
 String sql2 = ("EXEC store_proc_2");
 ResultSet rs2 = db.runQuery(sql1);
 while (rs2.next())
 {%>
  <option value="<%= rs2.getString("id_imnt_") %>"><%= rs2.getString("order_no") %></option>
  <%
  }
  rs2.close();
  %>
  </select>
  <input  type="submit" style= "name="drill"/>
</form>

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: When I am trying to collect both the id_imnt from Issuer name and ISIN in the nextpage.jsp using request.getparameter...and trying to put an iff condition like .. 
if(request.getParameter("IMNT")== null)
 {String main_id = request.getParameter("ISIN") }
else if(request.getParameter("ISIN") == null)
{String main_id = request.getParameter("IMNT")}

then when I am using this main_id.  It says main_id is not initialised

Comment: Embedding Java code in a JSP like this is considered to be a bad practice. Consider refactoring to do all the heavy lifting in a controller class and then forward to the JSP.

Comment: @Rontologist....Appreciate for the response, But its already been there, I just need to modify a little bit so as to incorporate same.

Answer (score 0):

do you have an extra underscore in the second

`rs2.getString()`

What exactly is the problem you are seeing? - you haven't really explained that very well...